# header enricher to set JMSReplyTo field and sending the same jms message using jms outbound channel adpter does not work

Tags: jms, spring-integration

I am using jms outbound channel adapter to send jms message ,but before sending the jms message i am setting JMSReplyTo to TEMP.Q3 .

Here is the sample configuration .

```
<int:channel id="OutgoingMessageChannel" />
<int:channel id="headerInputChannel" /> 

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="ticketOutbound" connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory" destination-name="TEMP.Q2" channel="OutgoingMessageChannel"/>

<int:header-enricher input-channel="headerInputChannel" output-channel="OutgoingMessageChannel">
    <int:header name="JMSReplyTo" value="TEMP.Q3"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

The above approach does not work ,i am not able to see "JMSReplyTo" field getting set to "TEMP.Q3"

I know i can use jms outbound gateway to do the same but i dont want it to be synchronous in nature.

Could anyone please let me know if this is possible using jms outbound channel adapter ?

Do i need to follow some other approach ?

**EDIT**

Here is the new working configuration .

```
<int:channel id="OutgoingMessageChannel" />
<int:channel id="headerInputChannel" /> 

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="ticketOutbound" connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory" destination-name="TEMP.Q2" channel="OutgoingMessageChannel"/>

<int:header-enricher input-channel="headerInputChannel" output-channel="OutgoingMessageChannel">
    <int:header name="jms_replyTo" ref="replyQueue"/>        
</int:header-enricher>

<bean id="replyQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value=" TEMP.Q3" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Spring Integration interacts with many protocols, it doesn't use the native header names internally, to avoid conflicts.

Use

```
<int:header name="jms_replyTo" ref="replyQueue"/>

<bean id="replyQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="TEMP.Q3" />
</bean>
```

and it will be mapped to the `JMSReplyTo` by the default header mapper.

**EDIT**:

The `JMSReplyTo` header must be a destination, not a simple string; use `ref=""` to point to a destination object (ActiveMQ example above).

Comment: Hi @gary ,this does not work ,still the default header mapper is not mapping the field "JMSReplyTo" to "TEMP.Q3" .

Comment: Where are you looking at the resulting message?

Comment: I tried "JMS_ReplyTo" also ,just in case if you had misspelled it ,but that also did not work for me .

Comment: Sorry , i am checking the field values Inside  "TEM.Q2" queue .

Comment: It must be a destination, not a String, see my edit (in the case of ActiveMQ).

Comment: Thanks Gary ,that does work ,I am using Websphere MQ ,after creating destination and referring it from header enricher ,the field "JMSReplyTo" does get set as "TEMP.Q3"  . Thanks ..